# Search in spreadsheets not working for new files created

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I create copies of my spreadsheet template on google docs with document list api and I realised that:

```
1. title queries works fine
2. content queries are not working(*) or partially working(**)
(*)for majority of spreadsheets: I searched every word from the content of a spreadsheet and I get no results
(**) for a few spreadsheets I find results for some words that are copied from template; the particular words queries are not working
3. If I update the spreadsheet after a few minutes all queries work fine.
(I make this searches from UI)
```

This are the steps for creating this files:

```
1. Copy spreadsheet template to root

private String sendPostCopyRequest(String authorizationToken, String resourceID, String title, int noRetries) throws IOException{ 
    /*
    resourceId = resource id for the template that i want to copy
    title = the title of the new file created
    */      
    String urlStr = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full";
    URL url = new URL(urlStr); 
    HttpURLConnection copyHttpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
    copyHttpUrlConn.setDoOutput(true); 
    copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

    String outputString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
            "<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"> " +
            "<id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/" + resourceID +"</id>" +
            " <title>" + title + "</title></entry>";

    copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "3.0");
    copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/atom+xml");

    copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", outputString.length() + "");
    copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + authorizationToken);

    OutputStream outputStream = copyHttpUrlConn.getOutputStream(); 

    outputStream.write(outputString.getBytes()); 
    copyHttpUrlConn.getResponseCode(); 

    return readIdFromResponse(copyHttpUrlConn.getInputStream()); 
}

2. I update some cells using this method:

public boolean setCellValue(SpreadsheetService spreadSheetService, SpreadsheetEntry entry, int worksheetNumber, String position, String value) throws IOException, ServiceException {

    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = entry.getWorksheets();
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(worksheetNumber);
    URL cellFeedUrl = worksheet.getCellFeedUrl();
    CellQuery query = new CellQuery(cellFeedUrl);
    query.setReturnEmpty(true);
    query.setRange(position);
    CellFeed cellFeed = spreadSheetService.query(query, CellFeed.class);
    CellEntry cell = cellFeed.getEntries().get(0);

    cell.changeInputValueLocal(value);
    cell.update();
    return true;

}

3. I move the created file to a new folder (collection)

    public DocumentListEntry moveSpreadSheet(DocsService docsService, String entryId, String destinationFolderDocId) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

    DocumentListEntry newEntry = null;
    newEntry = new com.google.gdata.data.docs.SpreadsheetEntry();
    newEntry.setId(entryId);
    String destFolderUri = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A"+ destinationFolderDocId + "/contents";

    return docsService.insert(new URL(destFolderUri), newEntry);

}

(the same results with gdata java sdk api 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7)
```

This happens from 2011-12-23 (with aproximation). For all the spreadsheets created with the same code before this date all queries work fine.

I can provide any other information on request.

Update:

1. This issue seems to appear also at uploading spreadsheets with conversion.
2. If I update the files after a period of time after creation/upload (~2 hours) the queries returns them in results.

Comment: Me, and several others reported GoogleDocs search in spreadsheets as broken (Google support forums, cannot find the link now). A Google employee confirmed that old documents were not indexed (AFAIK due to a bug at some point in time), and that we had to open and edit them for them to be re-indexed. However, today I found that search in spreadsheets was not working for a spreadsheat created 8 days ago, so I guess the bug has reappeared. I suggest you search the Google forums to see if you can find a current status.

Comment: I know about that post because I also reported there (this was the link - [link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!starred/docs/vEhI_HkKX3I)), but it was regarding the files created from UI. I will repost there to notify them (it appears that for the new uploaded files from UI is the same problem, but after a cell update is working fine)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be related to slowish Google indexing of spreadsheet contents.

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/docs/vEhI_HkKX3I/MGKqkryrx90J

"at the moment it can take about 10 minutes to index the content you've written into your spreadsheet. So if you type something in, and then search for it right away, it might not show up yet in  your list of document results. Give it a few more minutes (we are working on making this faster)"

Comment: My issue is not regarding slowish Google indexing... I am talking about files created since months ago (not 10 minutes)

Comment: Suggested workaround: write some code to loop over all your spreadsheets, touch a cell, and save. Then please share with the community :-)

Comment: I guess this is not working. All my spreadsheets are obtained using this steps: copy from template, update random cells from it. This means that I already do what you say. I will try to make it, maybe is working if I update them after a longer period after creation. I will come back with the result

Comment: It seems that it's working but only for "old files" (about ~2 hours old - I didn't make so many tests). I believed that because my document is created by updating cells this will not work. I will make a cron which will update the spreadsheets created in the last X hours until this problem is solved. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: Your welcome. You should not have to do this, though. This is an urgent bug for Google to fix, but for some reason it's not getting the attention it deserves.